# Navigation that highlights the active tab

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have looked around on here and on W3 but cant seem to figure out how to get the navigation menu I have to highlight the "tab" that I have clicked on and remove the highlight when I click on another tab.

My layout is 2 frames, left frame is some information about the items(working fine) the right frame has my nav bar in it.

This is the frame on the right:(the problem child)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#menu {
  text-align: justify;
}

#menu * {
  display: inline;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
.button {
display: block;
width: 155px;
height: 45px;
background: #4E9CAF;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateObjectIframe(which){
document.getElementById('navgo').innerHTML = '<'+'object id="bar" style="height:100%;width:100%;" name="bar" type="text/html" data="'+which.href+'"><\/object>';
}
</script>
</head
<body>

<div id="menu">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>

                    <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>
                    <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>
                    <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>  
                    <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>  
                    <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>  
                    <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>

                    <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>
                    <li><a class="button" href="#" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">TEST</a></li>
                    <ul>
                </div>
<div id="navgo" style="height:95%;width:100%;">
<object id="bar" name="bar">

</object>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to get this working please let me know your thoughts.
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Using JavaScript or jQuery or whatever simply add an 'active' class to the li or anchor that is clicked. Also when it's clicked just remove the active class from all elements that have it on. Then in your css still up the active class. This solution will work if you're only concerned with one page. If you want this to work over multiple pages of a website you'll have to really look at another solution with PHP or similar. Or alternatively on each other page place a class on the body tag which will tell the nav element which one should be 'on'.

Comment: How would you make it so onclick that one li is set to active and when I click another it make the one I just clicked active and removes that active class from the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple jQuery way to do what you're asking: http://jsfiddle.net/qs4w3/

You should be able to use the code in this fiddle to make your example work.

```
$("nav > ul > li > a").click(function() {
    $("nav > ul > li > a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this without jQuery?

Comment: Nothing I love it. This particular project does not use it :-/

Comment: I don't think you would be able to replicate this exact functionality without some form of dynamic scripting language. I may be wrong, but I don't think I am.

Comment: Got it without jQuery :D

Comment: Cool, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Updated the function to the following

```
function updateObjectIframe(which){
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = '<'+'object id="foo" style="height:100%;width:100%;" name="foo" type="text/html" data="'+which.href+'"><\/object>';
var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
Array.prototype.filter.call(testElements, function(testElement){
     testElement.style = "background: #4E9CAF;color: white;";
});
which.style = "background: #333; color: #fff;";
}
```